# Pandas: Group dataframe by condition "last value in column defines the group"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I've got a sorted dataframe (sorted by "customer_id" and "point_in_time") which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

testing = pd.DataFrame({"customer_id": (1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4), 
                        "point_in_time": (4,5,6,1,2,3,7,9,5,6,8,10,2,5),
                        "x": ("d", "a", "c", "ba", "cd", "d", "o", "a", "g", "f", "h", "d", "df", "b"),
                        "revenue": (np.nan, np.nan, 40, np.nan, np.nan, 23, np.nan, 10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 40, np.nan, 100)})
testing
```

[image]

Now I want to group the dataframe by "customer_id" and the "revenue". But with regard to "revenue" a group should start after the last existing revenue and end with the next occuring revenue.
So the groups should look like this:
[image]

If I had those groups I could easily do a

```
testing.groupby(["customer_id", "groups"])
```

I first tried to create those groups by first grouping by "customer_id" and applying a function to it in which I fill the missing values of "revenue":

```
def my_func(sub_df):
    sub_df["groups"] = sub_df["revenue"].fillna(method="bfill")
    sub_df.groupby("groups").apply(next_function)

testing.groupby(["customer_id"]).apply(my_func)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work if one customer has two revenues which are exactly the same. In this case after using fillna the group column of this customer will consist of only one value which does not allow additional grouping.

So how can this be done and what is the most efficient way to accomplish this task?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), last if necessary add `1`:

```
testing["groups"] = testing['revenue'].shift().notna().cumsum() + 1
print (testing)
    customer_id  point_in_time   x  revenue  groups
0             1              4   d      NaN       1
1             1              5   a      NaN       1
2             1              6   c     40.0       1
3             2              1  ba      NaN       2
4             2              2  cd      NaN       2
5             2              3   d     23.0       2
6             2              7   o      NaN       3
7             2              9   a     10.0       3
8             3              5   g      NaN       4
9             3              6   f      NaN       4
10            3              8   h      NaN       4
11            3             10   d     40.0       4
12            4              2  df      NaN       5
13            4              5   b    100.0       5
```